# How to get items tax_amount in magento 2.3 collectTotals()

Tags: magento2, cart, totals

All data I need in my module visible in next print

```
print_r($quote->collectTotals()->debug());
```

Output is show me

```
 Array
(
    [entity_id] => 3
    [store_id] => 1
    [base_subtotal_with_discount] => 1452.8
    [is_changed] => 1
    [trigger_recollect] => 0
    [is_persistent] => 0
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0 (Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Interceptor)] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 5
                    [quote_id] => 3
                    [base_price] => 54
                    [discount_percent] => 20
                    [discount_amount] => 356.4
                    [base_discount_amount] => 356.4
                    [tax_percent] => 8.375
                    [tax_amount] => 119.39
                    [base_tax_amount] => 119.39
```

It looks simple but how do I get the 
`collectTotals()->items->items['tax_amount']` ?

Simple var assign is also crash Magento

```
$myvar = $quote->collectTotals();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code hope it's work for you. I got a tax amount in shopping cart page using below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store_id = $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// get quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// get quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

//get tax amount

$TaxAmountValue = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getTaxAmount();
$BaseTaxAmountvalue = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getBaseTaxAmount();
```

Comment: Don't try to use Object Manager directly.

Comment: Yes, I know It's bad practice to directly use object manager